# Sending POST data with ajax from jquery to php - no response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to see an ajax response when submitting form in a result div ('ajax') - but cant manage to do that.

What is the problem? How can I achieve this? I see the post is being send in a net tab in console, but it doesnt work....

Here is my code:

index.php file:

```
$res = isset($_POST['login']) ? $_POST['login'] : '';
print '<form id="forma">
    <input type="text" name="login"/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="Javascript: AjaxForm.showForm(); return false;"/>
</form>
<div id="ajax">'.$res.'</div>'
```

and javascript file:

```
var AjaxForm =
{
    showForm: function()
    {
        var x = $('#forma').serialize();
        $.ajax({url: 'index.php', type: 'POST', data: x});
    }
}
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center: Ajax](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

add the success property to your ajax call

```
     $.ajax({url: 'index.php',
          type: 'POST', 
          data: x,
          success: function(data){
              //data is your response
              console.log(data);
          }
    });
```

Comment: @user7276366 you should add your code in the success callback, to manipulate the page base on the response.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
$(document).on('submit','#forma',function(){
     var data=$(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",            
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) 
              {
                 alert(data);
              }
        }); 
  return false;
});
```